# How to Add Bottom Sheet

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-cardview

I am trying to have a Recycler View with Cards within a bottom sheet where the user "scrolls" up  to reveal all of the Cards but I am having issues in accomplishing this. How can I have it so that the Recycler View with Cards is inside the bottom sheet? Any help is appreciated-I've been at this for days and cannot figure it out. Is there a way to do what the photo is showing in Android? Attached image is something what I am trying to replicate but just cannot seem to find anything that can do this:

[image]

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        if (supportActionBar != null)
            supportActionBar?.hide()

        val modelList = readFromAsset()

        val adapter = CustomAdapter(modelList, this)

        rcv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false) as RecyclerView.LayoutManager?
        rcv.adapter = adapter;

        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(object : CustomAdapter.ClickListener {
            override fun onClick(pos: Int, aView: View) {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, modelList.get(pos).name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })
    }

    private fun readFromAsset(): List<Model> {

        val modeList = mutableListOf<Model>()
        val bufferReader = application.assets.open("android_version.json").bufferedReader()
        val json_string = bufferReader.use {
            it.readText()
        }

        val jsonArray = JSONArray(json_string);
        for (i in 0..jsonArray.length() - 1) {
            val jsonObject: JSONObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
            val model = Model(jsonObject.getString("name"), jsonObject.getString("version"))
            modeList.add(model)
        }
        return modeList
    }
}
```

activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/rcv"/>
```

CustomAdapter.kt

```
class CustomAdapter(val modelList: List<Model>, val context: Context) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        (holder as ViewHolder).bind(modelList.get(position));
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        return ViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false))
    }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return modelList.size;
    }

    lateinit var mClickListener: ClickListener

    fun setOnItemClickListener(aClickListener: ClickListener) {
        mClickListener = aClickListener
    }

    interface ClickListener {
        fun onClick(pos: Int, aView: View)
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {

        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
            mClickListener.onClick(adapterPosition, itemView)
        }

        fun bind(model: Model): Unit {
            itemView.txt.text = model.name
            itemView.sub_txt.text = model.version

            val id = context.resources.getIdentifier(model.name.toLowerCase(), "drawable", context.packageName)
            itemView.img.setBackgroundResource(id)
        }

    }
}
```

row_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="30dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
        card_view:contentPadding="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sub_txt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img"
                android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="8sp"
                android:autoSizeMinTextSize="6sp"
                android:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
                android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                android:text="Title"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [BottomSheet](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/package-summary) to approach this.

your `BottomSheet` class will be like this.

```
    class CustomBottomSheet : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_bottomsheet)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val modelList = readFromAsset()

        val adapter = CustomAdapter(modelList, this)

        rcv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false) as RecyclerView.LayoutManager?
        rcv.adapter = adapter;

        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(object : CustomAdapter.ClickListener {
            override fun onClick(pos: Int, aView: View) {
                Toast.makeText(context, modelList.get(pos).name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })
    }

    private fun readFromAsset(): List<Model> {

        val modeList = mutableListOf<Model>()
        val bufferReader = context?.assets?.open("android_version.json").bufferedReader()
        val json_string = bufferReader.use {
            it.readText()
        }

        val jsonArray = JSONArray(json_string);
        for (i in 0..jsonArray.length() - 1) {
            val jsonObject: JSONObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
            val model = Model(jsonObject.getString("name"), jsonObject.getString("version"))
            modeList.add(model)
        }
        return modeList
    }
}
```

**`layout_bottomsheet`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="100dp"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rcv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then you need to show the bottomsheet from your activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        if (supportActionBar != null)
            supportActionBar?.hide()

  // show bottom sheet 
  val bottomSheetDialogFragment: BottomSheetDialogFragment = CustomBottomSheet()
        bottomSheetDialogFragment.show(
            supportFragmentManager, bottomSheetDialogFragment.tag
        )
  }
}
```

For more, you can read [this](https://tutorial.eyehunts.com/android/android-bottom-sheet-tutorial-example-kotlin/). or you can search about Bottomsheet. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help-I tried putting this in but it's not working correctly-the layout_bottom and BottomSheet aren't synching/working when I deploy to app.

Comment: Can you specify exactly what's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Bottom Sheet Dialog Or Bottom Sheet Dialog Fragment For Display Bottom Sheet In Adapter Class

BottomSheetDialog Example

```
View view = 
((FragmentActivity)context).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom_sheet, null);
           BottomSheetDialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(mContext);
            dialog.setContentView(view);
            dialog.show();
```

BottomsheetDialogFragment Example :
    Dialog Class

```
public class BottomsheetDialog extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup       container, 
@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom_sheet,container,false);
return v;
}
}
```

Call BottomsheetDialog in your Adapter Class Like This

```
 BottomSheetDialogFragment bottomSheetDialogFragment = new BottomsheetDialog();               
 bottomSheetDialogFragment.show(((FragmentActivity)mContext).getSupportFragmentManager(), bottomSheetDialogFragment.getTag());
```

Comment: I tried this but I couldn't get some of it to work with what I have. Do you happen to know of materials similar to the image I posted?

Answer (score 0):

First write a class extending BottomSheetDialogFragment class with your custom layout

```
class BaseBottomSheetDialogTest: BottomSheetDialogFragment(){
    companion object {
        fun newInstance(position: Int, callback: BaseBottomSheetDialogTestCallBack) = BaseBottomSheetDialogTest(callback).apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply {
                putInt("CUSTOM_DATA", position)
            }
         }
    }
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_custom_layout, container, false)
        return view
    }
}
```

Then call it like this

```
val bottomSheetDialog = BaseBottomSheetDialogTest.newInstance(0,CALL_BACK_INTERFACE_IF YOU_NEED)
bottomSheetDialog!!.show(fragmentManager, "TAG_STRING")
```

> This example is with how to pass data and a callback method.

Comment: Hmm I couldn't get this to work-I think I understand what you're suggesting. Is there a similar project you know of that I can look at?

Comment: Can you tell me which part you didn't understand or doesn't work?

Comment: You can look into this too

https://medium.com/@kosta.palash/using-bottomsheetdialogfragment-with-material-design-guideline-f9814c39b9fc

Comment: I am having trouble trying to combine the portion you suggested and the one I posted-I added it in but im getting error on AccountBalanceBottomSheetDialog and BaseBottomSheetDialogTestCallBack-I cant seem to make it turn out to be the recyclerview with cards within bottom sheet

Comment: BaseBottomSheetDialogTestCallBack is example of, how you can pass a callback method. Remove it if don't need it.